# Express - Route separation methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to find the best method to separate routes in Express. I'm aware of two methods and I was wondering what the difference is between them, and which one is considered 'best practice' (and why).

***Method one*** - exports

Lots of examples seem to use this method

app.js

```
var user = require('./routes/users');
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

routes/users.js

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.render('users', { title: 'Users', users: users });
};
```

***Method two*** -

This method is used in the express guide

app.js

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);
```

routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('users', { title: 'Users', users: users });
});

module.exports = router;
```

So as I said above, which one is the preferred method, and why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***Method three*** - use both

You should be taking advantage of both the router introduced in Express 4 and the modularization of your controllers.

**app.js**

```
var routes= require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var users = require('../routes/users');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/users', users);

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var users = require('../controllers/users');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', users.list);

module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/users.js**

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.render('users', { title: 'Users', users: users });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does this method have any performance issues associated with it?

Comment: @AshleyB It shouldn't have, since `app.get` etc uses the router internally anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious as the request flow will then look something like this:

app.js -> router/index.js -> router/users.js -> controllers/users.js -> views/users/user.hjs


It just doesn't look like the most efficient way of doing things. But i'll give it ago, cheers!

Comment: Don't forget that modules are cached, so it won't hinder I/O performance at runtime.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. Very helpful! Thanks.